# Firebase AuthStateListener failed to trigger function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi in my nativescript angular app i am checking at the starting of app whether user is logged in or not and call a function accordingly. Code given below:

```
ngOnInit() {
    firebase.init({
        onAuthStateChanged: function (data) {
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                this.navigateToHome();
            }
        },
    })
```

Error:

`Firebase AuthStateListener failed to trigger function (data) {
    if (data.loggedIn) {
        this.navigateToHome();
        ...<omitted>... } TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigateToHome' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

converting to arrow function solved the issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
    firebase.init({
        onAuthStateChanged: (data) => {
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                this.navigateToHome();
            }
        },
    })
```